# Assigning lexical order score to strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting, unicode

In my current project we have a strange kind of sorting system.

As opposed to the usual way of determining the order of elements by comparing them to one another, we first assign a numeric score to each element and then sort by this score. This way we can sort by different criteria by just changing the score assignment part.

What I want is to define a function on strings such that; f(a) < f(b) if a comes before b in lexical order and vice versa.

The strings are unicode and, we should support case insensitivity.

Is this possible?

Comment: For the record: probably my answer is a bit generic; but so is your question. For refined feedback; consider adding a [mcve] so that we can better understand how those score-sorting and string-sorting are meant to work out together.

Comment: Since unicode is just a 21-bit character set, just encode the string as all those 21-bit code points with the first character starting in the most significant bit and on down. You'll have to use `BigIntegers`. Also, this is cray cray.

Comment: What about `a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase())`?

Comment: @DavidConrad I am not familiar with the term "cray cray". Whats that mean?

Comment: @GhostCat Slang for crazy.

Answer (score 4):

Don't get me wrong, but this approach doesn't make sense. Because it means that you can **not** use Java's "default" mechanism to solve your problem; and that would be: you create own custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Meaning: when sorting collections/arrays of objects of some class, the *reasonable* way to define their ordering is by providing a comparator that can tell you for any two objects of that class how to order them.

Well, given your setup, that probably means: your comparator needs to be able to compute that score from the provided input objects. And then, it can use **further** information (like string values) to make further decisions.

Thinking about it again: you should really step back here. If you have a **huge** codebase that is already using this strange system; then well, you need to define a **scoring** function that reduces your strings to numbers; and make sure that the score value matches that f(a) < f(b) relation you are looking for. But if you are just starting; seriously: consider dropping your idea of using that *scoring* function. Instead simply use **different** comparator implementations to achieve sorting based on changing criteria.

Comment: This is a huge codebase and changing the sorting system is currently not an option so I'm looking for such a function.

Answer (score 4):

> What I want is to define a function on strings such that; f(a) < f(b) if a comes before b in lexical order and vice versa. The strings are unicode and, we should support case insensitivity.
>
> Is this possible?

No, it isn't unless your strings are limited in length. Suppose f("a") = 1. Then, obviously, f("aa") >= 2. Continuing this pattern, f("aa...a") >= n for "aa...a" containing n symbols. Since for any such string f("aa...a") < f("b"), f("b") must be bigger than any n.

Note that if you're using `BigDecimal` as values of your function instead of integer type, there is a way (though with Unicode it may be a bit tricky, basic idea is no normalize string and convert it byte-by-byte into decimal digits).

Comment: Why would you use `BigDecimal` rather than `BigInteger`?

Comment: Great catch; like both of you ... pointing out the logical flaw in the question; and that subtle but important detail regarding BigInteger vs BigDecimal ;-)

Comment: @DavidConrad Because `BigInteger` has the problem described in my answer. Basically, for any two integers `m, n` there are only `|m-n|-1` integers between them (finitely many), which is not the case for both lexicographically-ordered strings and `BigDecimal`s. (Formally speaking, `BigInteger` has ordinal ω which is too small and `BigDecimal` has ω+ω×Q (I think...) which is enough.)

Comment: @Abstraction, what if the strings are of limited length. Like, just 1 character. Is there a method to assign a number to a single unicode character that satisfies this relation?

Comment: @Can As I said in the answer: normalize the string, take bytes in something like UTF-32 (I'm assuming symbols with lesser byte values are 'less' in alphabetical sense), pad it with zeroes from the right up to maximum possible length, that would be your number. Note that length must be limited in *bytes*, not in *characters* (since Unicode lets you to add arbitrary amount of modifiers to a single character - like ด้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้้้้็็็็็้้้้้็็็็    - which once again allows my counterexample)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom Comparator. Something like this -

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class myString {
    private String s;   
    private int score;
    // getter & setter
    // ...
}


public class ScoredStringComparator implements Comparator<myString>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(myString x, myString y)
    {
        // Assume neither string is null.
        if (x.getScore() < y.getScore())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (x.getScore() > y.getScore())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And put the strings into s TreeSet.

```
TreeSet<myString> stringSet = new TreeSet<myString>(new ScoredStringComparator());
```

Now, when you need to update a string's score, you can do it in logarithmic time complexity.

```
stringSet.remove(aString);
aString.setScore(newScore);
stringSet.add(aString);
```

Comment: Yes, but I cannot use comparators. There's no "other" element to compare to.